# Find and Replace with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have this value, cutted from `.txt`:

```
,Request Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN
```

I am trying to find and replace the space with "_", like this:

```
#iterator to read lines of txt
#if conditions
trim_line=$(echo "$user" | awk '{gsub(" ", "_", $0); print}')
echo $trim_line
```

but the echo is showing:

```
Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN
```

Expected output:

```
,Request_Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN
```

Where is my bug?

**EDIT:
The echo of user is not the expected, it is:**

```
Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN
```

And should be:

```
,Request Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN
```

To do this operation I am using:

```
for user in $(cut -d: -f1 $FILENAME)
do (....) find/replace
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `,Request_Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN`

Comment: Looks like `$user` doesn't contain what you expect.

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $user`?

Comment: While I still think you should use `tr` over `awk`, it looks like this is not your current problem : `echo ",Request Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN" | awk '{gsub(" ", "_", $0); print}'` correctly outputs `,Request_Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN`

Comment: @TomFenech you are correct, question edited

Comment: You're looping over the first field of each line of `$FILENAME`, but if they contain spaces they are considered as two separate elements (as if they were on two lines). You should do your search/replace before looping over the data

Comment: you've got several valid answers. At least accept one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your use of a `for` loop to read the contents of your file. The shell splits the output of your command substitution `$(cut -d: -f1 $FILENAME)` on white space and you have one in the middle of your line, so it breaks.

Use a `while read` loop to read the file line by line:

```
while IFS=: read -r col junk; do
    col=${col// /_}
    # use $col here
done < "$FILENAME"
```

As others have mentioned, there's no need to use an external tool to make the substitution.

...That said, if you don't plan on doing something different (e.g. executing other commands) with each line, then the best option is to use awk:

```
awk -F: '{ gsub(/ /, "_", $1); print $1 }' "$FILENAME"
```

The output of this command is the first column of your input file, with the substitution made.

Comment: Shouldn't the field separator be , in both the examples?

Comment: The idea was to replace the use of `cut -d:`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try bash search and replace substring :

```
 echo $user
,Request Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN
 echo ${user// /_}                   ## For all the spaces
,Request_Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN
 echo ${user/ /_}                   ## For first match
```

This will replace all the blank spaces with `_`. Note that here two `/` are used after user. This is to do the search and replace operation on whole text. If you put only one `/` then search and replace would be done over first match.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already in an environment variable, the fastest way is to directly use built-in bash replacement feature:

```
echo "${user// /_/}"
```

With `awk`, set the separator as `,` or the space character will be interpreted as the separator.

```
echo ",Request Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN" | awk -F, '{gsub(" ", "_", $0); print}'

,Request_Id,dummy1,dummy2,dummyN
```

note: if it's just to replace a character in a raw string (no tokens, no fields), `bash`, `sed` and `tr` are best suited.